# Magento 2: How to get only the file name of Home Page Logo?

Tags: magento2.3, phtml, server-setup, webserver

is there a way to only get the filename of an Homepage logo in the logo.phtml template file? $block->getLogoSrc() in logo.phtml returns the URL to the logo, but I need only the filename like someimage.jpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [basename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function `<?= basename($block->getLogoSrc()) ?>` to get the filename.

Comment: Thank you. It helped.